# Can Amazon ask for my credit card statement?

Tags: privacy, european-union, fraud

I have problems with Amazon, I was trying to buy a 30 eur gift card for a birthday but they put the order on hold and blocked my account.

Then I got a mail stating that I should fax Amazon my latest credit card statement with my name and address. At first I disregarded it as phishing but then months later I tried to login and found out my account is just blocked. So I sent them an email and they sent the fax request again (see below).

It seems very fishy to me, no shop ever asked me to do this and I do a lot of online shopping. I cannot even do it, I don't have a card statement like that, it's a debit card actually and who uses fax in 2016?
I asked my bank if they had any experience with this but they haven't replied yet.

Is it even legal for Amazon to ask for this?

Thank you for any thoughts on this.

> Greetings from Amazon.de.
>
> Please note that your order is currently on hold pending the
>   verification of your billing information. We will be happy to proceed
>   with your order as soon as we receive a recent credit card statement
>   for the credit card you referenced for this order.
>
> At your earliest convenience, please fax us a statement which displays
>   the billing name and address for the card.
>
> You can find our fax number on the Amazon.de Help page:
>
> www.amazon.de/fax
>
> Alternatively, you can ask the issuing bank of your credit card to
>   contact us with verification of these details.
>
> You will not be able to access your account online until this
>   verification procedure has been completed. However, it is not
>   necessary to open a new account or place a new order; we will complete
>   the processing of outstanding orders once your billing information has
>   been verified.
>
> Thank you for your patience with our security measures. Please don't
>   hesitate to contact us by email at adressen-bestaetigung@amazon.de
>   should you have any questions.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Amazon.de http://www.amazon.de

There's no way to send them an email but their fax number is on their actual website.

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> ```
>  adressen-bestaetigung@amazon.de
> ```
>
> Technical details of permanent failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain
>   amazon.de by amazon-smtp.amazon.com. [207.171.188.180].
>
> The error that the other server returned was: 550 #5.1.0 Address
>   rejected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is legal for a company to ask for any information they want as a condition of doing business with you, so long as their request isn't proscribed by law.  I don't know of any jurisdiction where a request for banking or credit information is illegal.

(In this case, however, it does seem like you are being phished.  You could report the matter to your country's consumer protection agency.)

Comment: well my point is that they want my credit card statement so they will see my other transactions which is a weird and unacceptable requirment, the fax number is on their website so it looks legit

Comment: @headsvk: According to your post they did not ask to see other transactions.  They asked to see "the billing name and address for the card."  You could satisfy that request by obscuring all other details on whatever you send them.

Comment: that's true, if I had any statement like that I could do it, thanks

Comment: This is in fact true. Amazon blocks what it perceives as a risky order and puts the customer account on hold. The customer is supposed to email their recent CC statement. However, this experience is going to be changed soon so that customers can upload their CC statements via Amazon's website itself.

Source: I'm an Amazon employee

Comment: @goelakash: that would be a good answer (and while you're adding it, you could include how customers are supposed to tell such a request from an ordinary scam).

Comment: @TimLymington I don't know enough to comment on the legal aspects of this practice. From a purely common sense perspective, I believe that Amazon does have a right to request any document which it deems necessary to conduct business with any party, however customer unfriendly it maybe overall.

Comment: If you buy an item in a store, you want to return it, and have no receipt, the store will want proof of the purchase, and your credit card statement will show that. So they can suggest that you show them the statement and tell you that without it you won’t get a refund. This seems similar. The “right to request” also includes your “right to refuse”.